# How does Uniswap charge users for its 0.15% interface fee?

Tags: uniswap

Would like to know if anyone understands how Uniswap charges their [0.15% interface fee](https://support.uniswap.org/hc/en-us/articles/20131678274957-What-are-Uniswap-Labs-fees) for certain currencies? Was looking up the contracts and didn't see this fee mentioned.

If it's purely a front-end implementation for using their official interfaces, how do they actually 'charge' it? Do users end up signing for 2 transactions? One for paying the fee and one for the actual swap on the protocol?

Thanks in advance for any insights!